# Assinging the Id field in Apex results in error

Tags: apex

I'm attempting to assign the Id of an account using the code below.  However, I am getting an error with the following syntax.  How can I set the Id field on an sobject in Apex?

Example 1:

```
myAccount.put('id', theId);
```

Example 2:

```
myAccount.id = theId;
```

Both of these examples result in error. Is there another way of setting the Id field?

Comment: can you add what your variable type is?Also whats variable theId

Comment: What error are you getting, Dedo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a new object an Id that you desire.

```
Account acc = new Account(Id = 'someidhere');
acc.Field__c = 'someval';
update acc;
```

This works basically in place of querying for Account in the database, but you aren't actually **setting** the Id of the Account.  It's basically a way to get around using a query to set fields.

Answer (score 0):

**NOT WORK**

```
myAccount = [ SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :theId ];
myAccount.Id = theNewId;
```

**WORK**

```
myAccount = [ SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :theId ];

Account theAccount = new Account();
theAccount.Id = myAccount.Id;
theAccount.Name = 'New Name';
update theAccount;
```

Comment: I'm creating an account via new but later I clone it and want to assign it a new id. Should that work?

Comment: a new Id will only be assigned when you save the new record into the database. In order to clone without copying the original id, use theAccount.clone(false,true);